# Should one sit for Asher Yatzar?

Tags: blessing, standing-sitting, asher-yatzar

When saying Asher Yatzar, should one sit or stand?

Comment: http://askhalacha.com/index.php/knowledgebase/must-one-be-standing-up-when-saying-the-bracha-of-asher-yatzar/ but also https://dinonline.org/2019/12/15/walkng-while-saying-asher-yotzar/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm jumping the gun, but if no one here finds a source that says how to say Asher Yotzar then it is *clearly* permitted to do either one lechatchilah. The Mishnah Berurah, for instance, would have said; that's what he does.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how we define the status of the bracha of Asher Yatzar (see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/116792/asher-yatzar-bircas-hashevach-vs-bircas-haneenin)), if we define it as a bircas hashevach then there appear to be differing approaches.

The Pri Megadim in his intro to hilchos brachos, [ois 18](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40464&st=&pgnum=16&hilite=) (screen shot below) writes that if one wants to sit for Birchas Hashevach one can.

[image]

However, Rav Moshe Sternbuch in [Teshuvos V'hanhagos (cheilek gimmel, siman 76)](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49820&st=&pgnum=82&hilite=) writes, "שברכת השבח ראוי לכתחילה לברך מעומד" - *"Bircas Hashvach is fitting ideally to be said standing"*

Comment: How are these differing? One is baseline halacha and one is ideal.

Comment: I hear - I meant that they differ in as much as the Pri Megadim gives allowance for one to sit if they want. Whilst Rav Shternbuch underlines the ideal for it to be said standing.

Comment: That is just a difference in emphasis, not opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I once heard a Shiur from Rabbi Paysach Krohn that one should 100% stand when saying this bracha since we say point blank in the bracha  וְלַעֲמוד לְפָנֶיךָ and to stand before you, so it would kind of a contradiction not to stand.

Comment: What about according to the nuschaos that don't say that phrase?

Comment: I haven't seen any Asher Yatzors that delte this phrase.

Comment: See [Siddur Hageonim Vehamekubalim](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=21793#p=169), bottom of the page, who brings nuschaos that don't include it. Contemporary siddurim that delete it (based on a search on Sefaria) include Edos Hamizrach and Tehillas Hashem (Chabad).

Comment: Not to argue w R' Krohn, but that isn't what לעמוד means in this phrase. It's a synonym for להתקיים (which can also mean "stand", as in קוממיות). Here they both mean, exist, be present.

Comment: @MichoelR Maybe we can that the ultimate presence is to stand, like standing in Amidah.

Comment: @Russell Not saying it's impossible, just that there's no evidence from the word. Btw, this may be a difference between "pshat" and "drash", see for instance Devarim 18:5.