Does one need to stand when saying Asher Yoser
I want to know Sephardic sources more specifically, but all are welcome. Well any and all information really. My question is: Does one need to stand when saying Asher Yoser?

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/116787/should-one-sit-for-asher-yatzar

@YDJ while the OP did say all sources welcome, the answers to that question come from Ashkenazi sources, which leaves the question of the Sephardic opinion still open.
